# How do I get Express to serve my root app and API routes, and React Router 4 to serve my front end routes, at the same time?

Tags: reactjs, express, react-router-v4

For some reason, I can't seem to get a setup that serves both my Express routes properly, and my React Routes. While the initial route "/" works and loads the express Route properly, when I navigate from to "/login", I just end up with an empty page.

The main express file, `app.js` is configured to use three routers. IndexRouter loads the front end app, while UsersRouter and PollsRouter load the data:

```
app.use('/', IndexRouter);
app.use('/api/v1/users', UsersRouter);
app.use('/api/v1/polls', PollsRouter);
```

My express routes look like this (`controller.home` loads the view that in turns loads the compiled production React app, which I build in a subdirectory outside of the express app). The express routes in the IndexRouter seem to work:

```
router.get('/', controller.home);
router.get('/login', controller.home);
router.get('/dashboard', controller.home);
```

Here are my front end React Routes:

```
  <Router>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/" component={HomePage} />} />
      <Route exact path="/login"  component={LoginPage} />
      <Route exact path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
    </Switch>
  </Router>
```

What's going on? How do i even debug this? The front and back end sections both work perfectly on their own, they just don't seem to work together...

Comment: I assume your express routes run first when the server starts? And your express routes are supposed to return data to the views in your react router?

Comment: @MaxBaldwin I updated the question with some extra code and context, I hope it answers your question. Data routes are in the form "/api/v1/*", and seem to be working correctly. I think React Router 4 is the problem. I like React on the front end but I'm actually considering ditching RR4.

Comment: Sooo... If you want to bring your data down to the client with React Router, you need to use Relay or Apollo. Apollo > Relay these days. If you want to ditch React Router and serve your view from the Express routes you need to fetch your data in the `componentDidMount` of your component that is rendered in that view. You can use the set up your have right now. With your current set up, in each component your React Router serves, you can fetch your data via your Express API in `componentDidMount`.

Comment: @MaxBaldwin - You misunderstand me, loading data works great. The problem is that if I load React into the root "/" URL via express, and I click on a normal `<a href="/login"></a>` link, I end up with a blank React page. But running React from it's own folder with `yarn start` works perfectly. 
Note that in React Router 4, <HashRouter> seems to work but <BrowserRouter> does not work. Since this is an authenticated dashboard, SEO for the URL's is not a consideration, so it might be easiest just to use <HashRouter>.